# how we can execute one procedure in one database from another procedure in another data base

Tags: sql, plsql

i want to execute one procedure say p1 existing in schema s1 of db db1 
from procedure p2 existing in schema s2 of db db2.
Kindly suggest how we can do this in plsql with an example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag dbms used. Product specific question.

Comment: Have you tried anything first? If so, show us!

Answer (score 0):

In PLSQL you can try like this:

```
EXEC s1.myPackage.p1;
```

where [myPackage] is the optional package name, you need to provide it if the procedure is contained in a package.

Answer (score 0):

> create a dblink in s2 schema that connect to d1. Provide necessary
>   grants(P1 execute grants) to dblink user. Call the p1 from p2

```
create or replace s2.p2 as 
begin
s1.p1@dblink('parameters');
end s2.p2;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here when we need to connect to different DB we have Database Links
>   (DB Links).
>
> Steps needed

```
1) Create a DB Link


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_dblink
AS
BEGIN
<SCHEMA_NAME>.<PROCEDURE_NAME>@DBLINK_NAME(<PARAM>);
END;
```